# Smart replace repeated values python

Tags: python, replace

So I have a file and I want to go line by and replace some words that are very similar and that actually some of them are substrings of others:

```
uint8=("UINT8 ","PIN_UINT8 ")
uint16=("UINT16 ","PIN_UINT16 ")
uint32=("UINT32 ","PIN_UINT32 ")
uint64=("UINT64 ","PIN_UINT64 ")
int8=("INT8 ","PIN_INT32 ")
int16=("INT16 ","PIN_INT16 ")
int32=("INT32 ","PIN_INT32 ")
int64=("INT64 ","PIN_INT64 ")
```

Those are the replacements. But I need to be careful because `INT8` its a substring of `UINT8` so even if I have a match I need to check if it is a `UINT8` or `INT8`.

I've wrote some code but is far from working.

```
while pos!=-1:
                                print line[pos:]
                                if "INT8 " in line[pos:]:
                                    pos=line.find("INT8",pos_final)
                                    if "U" == line[pos-1]:
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*uint8)
                                    else:
                                        print line[pos-1]
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*int8)
                                    pos+=5 #len(PIN_)+1
                                elif "INT16 " in line[pos:]:
                                    pos=line.find("INT16",pos_final)
                                    if "U" == line[pos-1]:
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*uint16)
                                    else:
                                        print line[pos-1]
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*int16) 
                                    pos+=5                       
                                elif "INT32 " in line[pos:]:
                                    pos=line.find("INT32",pos_final)
                                    if "U" == line[pos-1]:
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*uint32)
                                    else:
                                        print line[pos-1]
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*int32) 
                                    pos+=5                       
                                elif "INT64 " in line[pos:]:
                                    pos=line.find("INT64",pos_final)
                                    if "U" == line[pos-1]:
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*uint64)
                                    else:
                                        print line[pos-1]
                                        line = line.rstrip().replace(*int64)
                                    pos+=5
                                else:
                                    pos =-1
```

Here there are some lines of the file so you can know if the response is correct and works:

> ```
> UINT32 CacheSize() const { return _cacheSize; }
> UINT32 LineSize() const { return _lineSize; }
> UINT32 Associativity(UINT64 obj, INT8 obj2) const { return _associativity; }
> VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, UINT32 & setIndex) const
> VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, UINT32 & setIndex, UINT32 & lineIndex) const
> {
>     const UINT32 lineMask = _lineSize - 1;
> ```

Comment: Just do the uint-replacements before the int-replacements and it should work...

Comment: maybe use regular expressions - `re` module

Comment: @L3viathan changing `INT8 ` to `PIN_INT8 ` it will change `PIN_UINT8 ` to `PIN_UPIN_INT8 `

Comment: @furas Ah, good point, didn't think of that. Try `re.sub(r'(U?INT\d+?)', r'PIN_\1', line)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't have `INT7`s in your file.

```
import re
text = """UINT32 CacheSize() const { return _cacheSize; }
    UINT32 LineSize() const { return _lineSize; }
    UINT32 Associativity(UINT64 obj, INT8 obj2) const { return _associativity; }
    VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, UINT32 & setIndex) const
    VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, UINT32 & setIndex, UINT32 & lineIndex) const
    {
        const UINT32 lineMask  = _lineSize - 1 INT8;
"""
for line in text.split("\n"):
    print re.sub(r'(U?INT\d+?)',r'PIN_\1', line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using re module, try below code

```
import re
text = """UINT32 CacheSize() const { return _cacheSize; }
    UINT32 LineSize() const { return _lineSize; }
    UINT32 Associativity(UINT64 obj, INT8 obj2) const { return _associativity; }
    VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, UINT32 & setIndex) const
    VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, UINT32 & setIndex, UINT32 & lineIndex) const
    {
        const UINT32 lineMask  = _lineSize - 1 INT8;
"""

for line in text.split("\n"):
    line = re.sub("UINT8 ","PIN_UINT8 ", line)
    line = re.sub("UINT16 ","PIN_UINT16 ", line)
    line = re.sub("UINT32 ","PIN_UINT32 ", line)
    line = re.sub("UINT64 ","PIN_UINT64 ", line)
    line = re.sub("[^UPIN_]INT8 ","PIN_INT32 ", line)
    line = re.sub("[^UPIN_]INT16 ","PIN_INT16 ", line)
    line = re.sub("[^UPIN_]INT32 ","PIN_INT32 ", line)
    line = re.sub("[^UPIN_]INT64 ","PIN_INT64 ", line)
    print "\t\t",line
```

**Output**

```
PIN_UINT32 CacheSize() const { return _cacheSize; }
PIN_UINT32 LineSize() const { return _lineSize; }
PIN_UINT32 Associativity(PIN_UINT64 obj,PIN_INT32 obj2) const { return _associativity; }
VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, PIN_UINT32 & setIndex) const
VOID SplitAddress(const ADDRINT addr, CACHE_TAG & tag, PIN_UINT32 & setIndex, PIN_UINT32 & lineIndex) const
{
    const PIN_UINT32 lineMask  = _lineSize - 1PIN_INT32 ;
```